# React Router quit the active class of parent '/' (parent) when child route clicked '/about' (child)

Tags: javascript, html, sass, react-router

I have a little issue in my `Navbar` and the paths.
When I'm in `<Layout/>` (path='/') page the home link is active and yellow, but when I click a child route the parent is still active and both yellow.

How do I get just printed one in yellow?

My code:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path='/' element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Home />} />
    <Route path='about' element={<About />} />
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

CSS

```
&.active {
  svg {
    color: #ffd700;
  }
```